# Redshift Limitation for Group By/String Issue

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have found few of limitation in the Redshift related to group by clause and string quotes. Like in mysql if we did not replace "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" of sql mode to null. It never allow to run the query without having the same column in the select query, which is used in group by clause.

In that same way, Redshift causes an issue to select the each column specifically in the select, which is used in the Group by clause.

The second issue, i have face is the related to string quote. If i have take the data type varchar for the column. Then still i need to remove the quotes from the value to run any query in Redshift. Like if i am using this query

```
select * 
from table_name 
where user_id = '10'
```

then it does not allow me to run the query until I did not remove the single quotes of the value 10.

Is someone have any idea about these kind of issue then please help!

Comment: please post your example sql inside your question

Comment: Hi Jon,

Here is an example for mysql. Like 

"select * from table_name where 1 group by column_name". Now this "column_name" should be in the select query. Then this query will work.

Comment: If `where user_id = '10'` gives an error, but `where user_id = 10` works, then the column  `user_id` is almost certainly **not** defined as `varchar`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No sir, i have defined that as varchar already

Comment: @JonScott

Jon here is example. Did you found any solution ?

Like "select * from table_name where 1 group by column_name". Now this "column_name" should be in the select query. Then this query will work.

Comment: as said above it's not varchar. make sure you have commited any updates - maybe restart your connection and take a look at the properties

Comment: @JonScott

Yes. I have tried many of ways. I have checked the connection etc.
Everything else is working fine.

Any idea !!